# Patching with ida pro

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, opcode, patch, ida

I have a program like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somma(x,y){
  return x+y;
}

int diff(x,y){
  return x-y;
}



int main(){
  int x=5;
  int y=4;
  printf("la somma e' %d", somma(x,y));
  printf("La differenza e' %d", diff(x,y));
}
```

I'm trying to patching it to replace the call of somma function with the diff function.
In E8 79 FF FF FF and the diff function has op E8 70 FF FF FF so what I tried to do is:
replace the op of somma function with diff ones. So my somma op becames E8 70 FF FF FF but when I try to execute it I receive a segmentation fault. Why? Wha's my error?

EDIT
These is a screen of my work.
[image: ida pro]

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply replace the offset with something else in some other place to replace what it calls. What you need to do is **calculate the relative offset from the caller offset to the function offset:** `destination - source - 5`. So, for example, if the location of the opcode where you call the `somma` is `0x348232`, and the location of `somma` is `0x858232`, so the relative offset would be `0x858232-0x348232-5 = 0x50FFFB`, and you'd have to replace the original bytes with `E8 FB FF 50 00`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my answer with a screen of my work! Can you show me where I can find the location of the op and the location of somma? I can't find it!

Comment: @UsiUsi location of the somma can be calculated as FFFFFF70 = x - 1F1B - 5, and x is 0x1E90.

Comment: ok! so If I understand FFFFFF70 (litte endian) is the OP, 1F1B is the position in the text. And what is 0x1E90??? why I must sub 5? can you explain me? thanks

Comment: @UsiUsi that would be the destination for OP at 0x1F1B. the reason why you need to subtract 5 is that `eip`, the program counter, would be pointing the next opcode(which would be the address of the original opcode + the size of the instruction, which in this case is 5) by the time it reads the offset.

Comment: mmm but what I can't understand is... what I must replace of _diff funct to make the call of that pinging to the _sub function?

Comment: @UsiUsi I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Can you tell me what I must edit to make the address of _somma pointing to the address of _diff-... I can't understand! :S

Comment: @UsiUsi You need to edit all the calls that calls `_somma`. From the screenshot, I only see one call, which is at 0x1F1B